# Surface on 3d points

Tags: matlab

I have a lot of points on 3D space, such as:

```
[177,867390625000, -173,140625000000, -149,666937500000],
[202,519976190476, -163,001285714286, -77,1924761904762],
[175,576234375000, -148,980296875000, -135,779421875000],
[244,798280000000, -210,332080000000, -177,070066666667],
[240,668416666667, -156,703083333333, -135,545016666667]
```

and I would like to create a surface that plots these points.

Answer (score 0):

The format of your data is not clear. If each line is a coordinate, that is

```
X = [177, 173, ...]
 Y = [-77, ...]
```

Then, you can plot them by

```
plot(X, Y, Z, '.b')
```

where the dot means "plot them as individual points, without connecting them with lines". But first, remove the commas in your numbers (replace them with dots if they are decimal points)

Answer (score 0):

the format of data is:
[x1 y1 z1
x2 y2 z2
.......]

I've already plot the points using  the function "scatter3", now I've to create a surface that plots these points! 
I tried to use the function scatteredInterpolant(x,y,z,v) but I don't know the input function v !!!

Comment: Hi rachi! Instead of writing this as an answer, you should better modify the question itself.